# Adding css class not working some time in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I am detecting a class from color picker and want to change the class of header tag.

```
// to find specific header id which having bgt css class . Detecting id from a div which have css class .ss

$(document.body).on('click', '.bgt', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    id = $(this).closest('div').find('.ss').attr('id');
    var $this = $('#h'+id); 
    var $dv = $this.closest('div');
    var nstr= $dv.attr('class');
    var newstrt = nstr;
    //heder tag where I am to add class
    $("#h"+id).addClass(newstrt);
```

this some time work some time not work
       Please help

Comment: you should open your js console and look at any error message every time it doesn't work.

Comment: looks very messy to me. What do you want to achieve? firstly you are finding a div's ID, then you are doing `$("#" + id)`. and then again those messy things...

Comment: you need to share a html sample... also check your browser console to see whether there are any errors

Comment: check if there is duplication of id..

Comment: Ashish Kumar header tag in a loop and having different unique id each one.

Answer (score 2):

You should quote to the class you want to add:

```
$("#h"+id).addClass("newstrt");
```

Comment: Assuming `newstart` is the desired class name and not a variable declared elsewhere this is correct.

Comment: newstrt is a variable which have a class name so in qoute write same name newsrtr.
Actually newstrt have class with name bg-color-green.
And these are changing time to time

Comment: where did you see bg-color-green?

Comment: bg-color-green this class I am detecting from a dropdown and want to apply at header.

Answer (score 1):

Please change `e.preeventDefault();`

to

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: @Attarisoft  where u declared newstrt

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `var id` instead just `id`

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.bgt', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var id = $(this).closest('div').find('.ss').attr('id');

//var $this = $('#h'+id); 
//var $dv = $this.closest('div');
//var nstr= $dv.attr('class');
//var nstrr = nstr;

//heder tag where I am to add class
$("#h"+id).addClass(newstrt);
```

If look @ your code. I don't think commented four lines are required.

Comment: These four lines are detecting class name which I want to apply.

Comment: @Pramod what is newstrt here

Comment: @Attarisoft you haven't declare newstrt in that four lines. So I commented that four lines

Comment: @prash If you look @ that four lines where is newstrt? I thought he declare variable some where else